# How to calculate the probability of error in an AWGN channel in Python?

Tags: python, probability

I found a paper on the calculation of probabilities of error. However, I didn't know how to plot the graph using equation 3 and 4.
These are the list of equations:

[image]

[image]

And this is the graph:

[image]

This is my Python code to generate the graph, however, it does not shows the correct graph:

```
x=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
sigma=np.array(x)
bins=4+sigma 
mu=bins/4
y=1/(sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *np.exp( - (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2))                                       

plt.plot(x,np.log10(y))
plt.xlabel('Noise variance')
plt.ylabel('Probability of error')
plt.scatter(x,np.log10(y))
plt.show()
```

I hope that anyone in this forum may guide me to plot this graph.
Thank you.